# Is there an offline thesaurus? It should be searchable via a node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, hashtable

I need an offline thesaurus. In a nutshell, I need to get the synonyms of certain keywords, and see which one is most relevant.

For example, if I have the keywords "phone", "computer" and "television", perhaps the synonym "electronics" is the most relevant one for all the keywords.

My app is JavaScript (node.js) so ideally I'd like to be able to load the thesaurus in memory and do a lookup that way. Or perhaps the thesaurus can be loaded into a database.

Do any of you know how this can be accomplished? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try wordnet. Use a library like https://github.com/dariuszdziuk/wordnet.git

Answer (score 0):

you can download the core wordnet database from here http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/current-version/ or you can just use the core database of the most used terms http://wordnetcode.princeton.edu/standoff-files/core-wordnet.txt